# Passing a bool as a param. C++

Tags: c++, boolean, boolean-logic

what I am trying to do is an example below.

let's first define a bool.

```
bool cat = {false};
```

lets make a fake bool here.

```
bool setcat(bool booltoset)
{
 booltoset = true; 
 return booltoset;
}
```

now lets call it with cat.

```
printf("cat is %s", cat?"true":"false"); //set cat as false.
```

my question is; is it possible to actually pass a bool through an argument than set that bool?

Comment: Look for "reference" in your C++ tutorial. The answer to your question: yes, it is possible.

Comment: pass the bool as a reference like so : `bool setcat(bool& booltoset)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass by reference, i.e.:

```
void setcat(bool& booltoset)
{
 booltoset = true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any function argument is just a variable with scope identical to the function body. If it's an ordinary automatic variable, then changing it has not effect on the caller. This is sometimes useful: you can actually use the arguments, for example:

```
template<typename F>
void for_each(noexcept_it i, const noexcept_it end, const F &f) noexcept(noexcept(f))
{
   for(; i!=end; ++i) f(i);   // use i as iteration variable.
}
```

though the compiler will optimise such things anyway in most cases.